# MSSQL Server Database Trigger Permissions - issue after migrating from 2008 to 2017 Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, trigger, security, sql-server-2017

I have some triggers set up on a database (Dynamics NAV) across various tables for Insert, Update, Delete.  The triggers write to a separate database to log the DB, Table, RowId and date/time.  The triggers worked in 2008 SQL using the "WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER" command.

On another server, 2017 SQL Cluster, I have the same triggers running (different tables) without the EXECUTE AS OWNER.  Everything worked fine.

We moved the Dynamics NAV database from 2008 to 2017 (separate server to the other applications as it does not support SQL Clusters).  The move was a SQL.BAK export/import

Everything works OTHER than the trigger.

I've removed the EXECUTE AS to mirror the other 2017 server, but have had no luck

The Dynamics NAV DB is owned by "MyAdminAcc" and the DB it writes into (BI) is owned by the same user.

When I update the table through SSMS the trigger works
When I use the application and perform an update using my standard user (not the MyAdminAcc user) it works
When a colleague in IT runs the application it works
When all accounting staff run, it fails (bad username/password).

The trigger seems to be running as DBO

I've looked in SECURITY for my user and the staff,  they have the same access
I've checked the database SECURITY for the same, again it's the same

I can't work out why this is now not working.

This is the UPDATE trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[bi_AR_U_UK]
   ON  [dbo].[Acme UK$Customer]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

insert into [BI].[trigger].[nav_arp_account] ([db], [tb], [accno], 
                                              [change], [insertedon] )
select 'Dynamics_Test','Acme UK$Customer',[no_], 'Updated', GETDATE()
from inserted;

END
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Have you compared the server level security for the `Logins` on the old server to the new server, especially the one's that pertain to your accounting staff?

Comment: UPDATE
I found my user, and a colleague were members of an AD group (SQL Admins) which has SYSADMIN role.

When I remove that it fails for me also.

So I know that will work BUT I don't have all staff on SYSADMIN on the Cluster where it is working

Comment: Right, I suspected it was a group disparity. Verify closely all AD Groups (including groups that are children of other groups on the AD side), SQL `Roles`, and the individual `Logins` themselves on the old server.

Comment: Thanks JD.  It's an odd one, not helped by how NAV pushes its own security objects into SQL.  Now trying to work out how I can see what is different.

2008 Server User A
  1) Read/Write to NAV DB (default schema is their name - which is what NAV does)
  2) Access to BI Database via an AD Group (Read/Write) (no default schema)

2017 Server
  1) Read/Write to NAV DB (default schema is their name - which is what NAV does)
  2) Access to BI Database via an AD Group (Read/Write) (no default schema)

2017 Cluster (Different DBs)
  1) Access to ERP & BI via AD Group (same as on 2017 above)

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to check on the permissions in SQL to list each DB and what / how they gain access?  I've tried

SELECT  
default_database_name,
[UserName] = ulogin.[name],
[UserType] = CASE princ.[type] WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User' WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group' END,  
[DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name], [Role] = null,
[PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
[PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
[ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
WHEN 1 THEN obj.type_desc
ELSE perm.[class_desc] END, [ObjectName] =

Comment: CASE perm.[class] 
WHEN 1 THEN OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id)
WHEN 3 THEN schem.[name]
WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name] END, [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM sys.database_principals princ                
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]         
LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id] 
LEFT JOIN sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id  AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]

Comment: ..

LEFT JOIN sys.schemas schem ON schem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE princ.[type] IN ('S','U','G') AND princ.[name] NOT IN ('sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA') and  princ.name in ('%user%');

Comment: You might try to run `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE YourDatabase TO CurrentOwner` on the restored database. I remember this was needed for these types of triggers to work.

Comment: Thanks Rois.  Sadly that had no effect

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::BI TO [domain\MyAdmin];

Same error.

If I do an update via Excel it works as the standard user

"insert into bi.[trigger].nav_arp_account (db, tb, accno, change, insertedon)
select 'SSMS','SSMS','TSSMSEST','update',getdate();

select * from bi.[trigger].nav_arp_account order by 5 desc;"

Updates the table and then shows me the log.

If I run the application, with the trigger, it errors

Comment: For now I have created my tables inside the app so it works.  Annoying as I can't remember what I did in January to get this to work or understand the underlying issue on teh permisisons